# iOS Load image from URL specifying size

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, request, size

Recently our App needs a replacement in image fetching logic, such that client should request an image with its size (image is built from server dynamically).

Image URL has the following format:
`http://image.server.url/path?width={{width}}&height={{height}}`

Most of the custom views are built in the following pattern:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        // do some initializations
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setImageURL:(NSURL *)URL {
    // do image fetching
}
```

And it is instantiated as:

```
SomeView *view = [[SomeView alloc] init];
view.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"..."];
[self addSubview:view];
```

This was not a problem (as all images' size are static), but when requesting image having dynamic size is unavailable because, as image fetching is run before `-layoutSubviews` is called, target image container's size is always zero.

After all, we need to figure out the timing when the layout is finished (using observer for image containers), or have static size for all image containers.

What would be the best solution for this?

Comment: The best solution would be to load network assets asynchronously, ie. once the download is complete, you update your UI with "what's really real". In practice this means that while the network assets are loading, you either show an animated progress graphic ("loading! wait!") or, a placeholder asset (low-res graphic while you get the real one)

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that maybe you don't need "exact" size of the image, because image could be scaled up or down. In my opinion you need close enough size of the image. Because (as I guess) image size is determined by screen size, (which is determined by device), you could prepare function for images, that return right size for right device.

You can know ab front the sizes for iPhone 4, iPhone 5,.... and then load correct size of the image (which container will be load after layoutSubviews)

Second idea is (as xaphod mention) that you load all sizes when app is downloaded and then load correct  size in layoutSubviews. But be aware, if there is a lot of images in a lot of sizes, then this could be a but huge space consumption for a images that will never be placed in an app.

Answer (score 0):

Load image from URL specifying size Also, According to iPhone Device size.

Here, the example that i have been using. Unfortunately, it is in **Swift** but do not worried about this it will give the basic idea how to do with objective-c. Also, the main things is to according to the device size image downloading.

**Create Class**

```
import UIKit

public class ImageService: NSObject {

     public enum ImageMode:String {
          case Uniform = "Uniform"
          case Zoom = "Zoom"
          case Pad = "Pad"

     var description : String {
        get {
            return self.rawValue
        }
     }
  }
   public func buildImageString(imageName:String, imageMode:ImageMode, size:CGSize, scale:CGFloat)-> NSURL{
      return NSURL(string: MonsciergeCoreKit.repository().apiRoot + "/v1/Images?imagePath=\(imageName)&mode=\(imageMode.description)&width=\(Int(size.width * scale))&height=\(Int(size.height * scale))")!
   }

}
```

**Usage**

You can change values according to your usage.
UIScreen.mainScreen().scale line gives you image size according to your device.

```
    let url = ImageService().buildImageString("ImageName", imageMode: .Zoom, size:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, headerHeight), scale:UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
```